# all calls to an inline function must be recompiled?

Tags: c++, performance, inline

I need to know how does this thing work? By this i mean " all calls to an inline function must be recompiled". I am reading a book which says that each time the inline function is used in our program, the compiler will recompile the short function definition and place a copy of this compiled short definition in your code.

I don't understand this at all. An explanation with example showing the whole proces will be highly appreciated. Also, could you please explain how does it improve the efficiency.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have this code:

```
void foo() { bar(); }

int main()
{
   foo();
   foo();
   foo();
}
```

If `foo` is inlined, then the compiler will essentially rewrite the code as:

```
int main()
{
   bar();
   bar();
   bar();
}
```

Now if instead of `bar();` you had a more complex piece of code, then that piece of code would appear (and be compiled) three times, rather than just once.

You trade the cost of a function call against increased and repetitive code.

The compiler may well refuse to actually inline a function. If you ever take the address of `foo` and pass it somewhere outside, you cannot even get around creating a stand-alone version. In practice, a happy mix of standalones and inlining will happen, depending on what fits best. (More important to what code ends up being generated is the effect of the `inline` keyword on the one-definition rule, though.)

Answer (score 3):

An inline function takes the code and inserts a copy everywhere it is used (hence inline) - this saves the cost of a function call.

Obviosuly if you change the function then the copy must be changed everywhere it is used - and each of those files (or code blocks) must be recompiled

Comment: Awesome and Simply explained. Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function

This means compiler will expand the inline function call to function definition. In other words the complete body of the function is replaced in every place the call is made.
Whereas for a normal function, the function definition is kept in one place and, compiler generates code to call the function whenever function is called in your code.

Also note that specifying a function as inline is only a request and compilers shall ignore this request too.